# Landing Page Button Organization

Tags: qt, qml

I am using a template to create an app using QT Creator and QML and am hoping to create a landing page that allows users to select which "page" they want to navigate to by clicking an icon.

I've figured out how to get a button on the landing page and have it open another page. However, I am using x and y positions of the button and it doesn't scale correctly when the window size changes.

Ultimately, I am trying to put 6 buttons on the landing page in a way that scales correctly.

I have attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88zEU.png)  of my ideal Landing Page design and have also attached code for what I already have.

I hope I was able to explain this well enough. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick 2.6

import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4


import "components" as Components

//BACKGROUND COLOR
Rectangle {
    signal signInClicked(string tourId)

    color: "#242424"

    AnimatedImage {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: app.landingpageBackground
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        visible: source > ""
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#00000000";}
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#00000000";}
        }
    }

//TITLE TEXT

    Text {
        id: titleText

        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            top: parent.top
            topMargin: app.height/10
        }

        font.family: app.customTitleFont.name

        text: app.info.title
        font {
            pointSize: 60
            pointSize: app.titleFontSize * 1.4
        }
        color: "#00000000"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    }

Button {
        id: signInButton

        anchors {
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: 60 * app.scaleFactor
        }

        opacity: 0.0
        style: ButtonStyle {
            id: btnStyle

            property real width: parent.width
            label: Text {
                id: lbl

                text: signInButton.text
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                width: parent.width
                maximumLineCount: 2
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                color: app.titleColor
                font.family: app.customTextFont.name
                font.pointSize: app.baseFontSize
            }

            background: Rectangle {
                color: Qt.darker(app.headerBackgroundColor, 1.2)
                border.color: app.titleColor
                radius: app.scaleFactor * 2
            }
        }
        height: implicitHeight < app.units(56) ? app.units(56) : undefined // set minHeight = 64, otherwise let it scale by content height which is the default behavior
        width: Math.min(0.5 * parent.width, app.units(250))
        text: qsTr("Let's Play!")

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                signInClicked("");
            }
        }

        NumberAnimation{
            id: signInButtonAnimation
            target: signInButton
            running: false
            properties: "opacity"
            from: 0.0
            to: 1.0
            easing.type: Easing.InQuad
            duration: 1000
        }
    }

 AboutPage {
        id: aboutPage
    }

    NewsAndUpdates {
            id: newsPage

    }

    ProgramsPage {
        id: programsPage
    }

    Connections {
        target: app

        onUrlParametersChanged: {
            if (app.urlParameters.hasOwnProperty("appid")) {
                signInClicked(app.urlParameters.appid)
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        signInButtonAnimation.start()
    }

}
```

Comment: Use [RowLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html) instead, absolute position is terrible and can cause a lot of trouble

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you're explicitly setting x and y position. I see that you're using anchors to center the button horizontally. When you say you want it to "scale correctly", does that mean you want all of the buttons to be centered together?

Comment: @JarMan - you're right, there is no absolute positioning for the button that I have in the code currently. The button that is in the code is default from the template. 

Yes, by "scale correctly" I mean I would like all buttons to be centered together in a grid like format.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-usecase-layouts.html) should help you. You haven't really defined what you want very well, but I'll show you some examples so you can hopefully take from it what you need.

QML has the concept of "positioners" and "layouts". Positioners help automatically position your objects neatly on the screen. And Layouts try to do that too, but can also stretch your objects to fill available space.

**Row:**

You can arrange all your buttons in a row and center the row horizontally.

```
Row {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    Button { id: btn1 }
    Button { id: btn2 }
    ...
}
```

**Grid:**

Similarly, Grid is a positioner that arranges objects into a grid:

```
Grid {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    columns: 3
    Button { id: btn1 }
    Button { id: btn2 }
    ...
}
```

**GridLayout:**

A GridLayout is just like a Grid, but it can also resize the objects to fill up the space. My opinion is layouts can do more, but they're often trickier to use. In this example, the first button should be a fixed size, while the second button should fill up the remaining width.

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    rows: 2
    Button { id: btn1; Layout.preferredWidth: 200 }
    Button { id: btn2; Layout.fillWidth: true}
    ...
}
```